# ¿Cuál es la sintaxis en el where de una consulta en SQL Server para obtener los valores NULL y también los registros con un valor = x?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql

Por ejemplo: tengo la tabla trabajador con los campos id, nombre, edad.

Necesito obtener todos los trabajadores en los cuales la edad sea igual a 30 y también en los cuales el campo de edad es NULL.

Comment: `where edad=30 or edad is null` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso se haria colocando:

```
select blahblah
from blahblah
where
    condicion1
    and condicion2
    and (edad is null or edad = 30)
```

Si fuera pgsql se podria hacer esto:

```
where
    condicion1
    and condicion2
    and coalesce(edad, 30) = 30
```

Pero no estoy seguro del soporte de `coalesce` en sqlserver asi que

Comment: Me sirvió tu solución. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido Roberto. Si alguna de las propuestas tu ayuda, puedes hacer click en la flecha hacia arriba a la izquireda de la respuesta. y si una de ellas es **la respuesta**, puedes indicarlo seleccionando con el gancho que también está con esas flechas.

Comment: @eftshift0 el usuario es nuevo y no tiene reputación para poder dar un voto positivo. Sin embargo, aceptó tu respuesta y con eso debería ser suficiente

Answer (score 0):

Esto es bastante directo y rápido de hacer, la verdad. Sin embargo, hay diferentes formas y puedes obtener diferente performance dependiendo de la cantidad de datos e índices de tu tabla.

La forma más simple es:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Trabajador
WHERE edad = 30
OR edad IS NULL;
```

Otra forma es usando `ISNULL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Trabajador
WHERE ISNULL(edad,30) = 30;
```

O una función equivalente en cuanto a resultado (pero que se expande en un `CASE WHEN`):

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Trabajador
WHERE COALESCE(edad,30) = 30;
```